# How to make Magento support some French Characters?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've been trying to make Magento support some french characters but haven't got any success so far.

The French text that I would want to display is:

```
Vous aimerez peut-être aussi
```

But somehow, it appears like this:

[image]

Its been the same with several other characters. Magento does use UTF-8 by default, but still these characters are not being displayed (surprisingly, because StackOverflow is using UTF-8 and is able to display the characters)
I noticed that ISO-8859-1 is able to display them, tried to change the default character encoding by editing the following file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml
```

And changed the node `<default_charset>`'s value to `ISO-8859-1`.

Now Firefox displays the following in Page Info, and the text is still not being displayed properly:

[image]

I am using Eclipse to edit the `phtml` files and often these french texts are being generated by php code.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: just a guess, is it stored in the db? What encoding does your db use?

Comment: Its MySql with all its default values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have wrong encoding either in database or in documents , translation files. Ensure that the encoding is `utf-8` all the way in all places that you deal with

- magento
- database
- document encoding while editing

Comment: that means the MySql should also be using UTF-8 for storing its data, right?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! My Eclipse wasn't using UTF-8, and as soon as I turned it to UTF-8, it started working :)