# How to convert French accented words into codes for Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, non-ascii-characters

I have two versions for my store - English and French. And I am doing the translation from English to French in `app/locale/fr_FR/Mage_Page.csv`

I notice that I have to use some **codes** for certain French characters, such as `En-tÃªte de page` for `tête de page`.

So if I have French words like `100% Magasinage sécurisé`, how can use convert it into **codes** like `En-tÃªte de page`?

Comment: I'd be surprised if character encoding wouldn't allow you to do this without using the codes.  Possible dupicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510889/how-to-make-magento-support-some-french-characters

Comment: it is already set to `<default_charset>utf-8</default_charset>`. I think it could some bug from Magento...

Comment: I'm not great at character encoding, but there are so many international sites using accents that if it was a Magento bug, it would be pretty well known.  Things like your .csv may also have incorrect character encoding.

Comment: it has this kind of encoding `Description par dÃ©faut`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can come from the encoding of your file Mage_Page.php. If you use linux, I think that you have it in your file's properties and if you use Windows, you can check with notepad++. Richard B. gave a good link that in my opinion might solve the problem.
I'm using french on all the magento website that we produce and I do not have any problem like that so it must come from the encoding of your file.
One last thing : if your file is utf8 encoded, it means that your text was imported from a different one and editor did what it could but not successfully to change the characters (can happen with text from excel).

Comment: And you are right - it is the encoding of Mage_Page.csv. I must set it to utf-8.